# Not able to parse apache access.log with logstash grok

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Alright so i'm using logstash to parse apache access.log i can get the data pushed but could not parse it

this is my logstash.conf

```
filter {
        grok {
                match => {
                        "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"
                }
        }
        date {
                match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
        }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
```

and this is a example of my apache log

```
[26/May/2021:14:03:31 +0000] **.**.**.** **.**.**.** - example-example.example.com "-" "ExampleMonitoring/1.0" **.**.**.** - "GET /sat0-ldap/OPX4/localhost:8402/superviser-dynamic HTTP/1.1" 200 1791 **.**.**.*** **.**.**.***
```

note: everything in stars * is a IP adress

Comment: Try this grok pattern: `\[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] %{IP:ip1} %{IP:ip2} (-|%{DATA:myfield1}) %{IPORHOST:hostname} \"(-|%{DATA:myfield2})\" \"%{DATA:useragent}\" %{IP:ip3} (-|%{DATA:myfield3}) "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{IP:ip4} %{IP:ip5}`
You'll probably want to the give the `myfield` and `ip` fields more readable names. Hth!

Answer (score 0):

An [Apache access.log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog) can have almost any format. The LogFormat directive allows great flexibility in determine what entries are logged in what order.

There are a couple of formats often used in several httpd implentations, called Common Log Format and Combined Log Format, so logstash includes grok patterns that match these.

Your log is not in the COMBINEDAPACHELOG format, which is

```
%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" (?:-|%{NUMBER:response}) (?:-|%{NUMBER:bytes}) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}
```

The logstash pattern is defined [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/7f94275ec8212f7f0aa6eb4ac5dbf3d70cd05cac/patterns/legacy/httpd#L6). You will need to create a custom pattern that matches your log format.